# My update form won't update the previous data

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, prepared-statement

I suppose there's a much cleaner way of doing it, but I'm trying to archieve that I can edit the data in a update form. The problem is that the update query isn't working. Could anyone please pinpoint out the mistake a made. Thanks anyway.

```
public function editData()
{
    if (isset($_GET['pid']))
    {
        $target = $_GET['pid'];
        if($edit = $this->db->prepare("SELECT id, title, price, description, address, includ, duration FROM trips WHERE id=?"))
        {
            $edit->bind_param('i', $target);
            $edit->execute();
            $edit->store_result();
            $edit->bind_result($id, $name, $price, $description, $address, $includ, $duration);
            $edit->fetch();
            $this->editForm($id, $name, $price, $description, $address, $includ, $duration);
        }
        else
        {
            echo "something went wrong";
        }
    }
}
```

```
public function editForm($id, $name, $price, $description, $address, $includ, $duration)
{
    $add .= '<form name="invent" method="post"  action="index.php?res=resources&adm=admin&page=inventory.php&pid=$id" class="ínvent" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
    $add .= '<fieldset>';
    $add .= '<legend>Add products</legend>';
    $add .= "<label for='name'></label>";
    $add .= "<input type='text' name='user' value='".$name."' />";
    $add .= '</br>';
    $add .= "<label for='price'>price</label>";
    $add .= "<input type='number' name='price' value='".$price."'  />";
    $add .= '</br>';
    $add .= "<label for='description'>description</label>";
    $add .= "<textarea name='description' rows='10' cols= '80'>'".$description."' </textarea>";
    $add .= '</br>';
    $add .= "<label for='address'>address</label>";
    $add .= "<input name='address'  type='text' value='".$address."'>";
    $add .= '</br>';
    $add .= "<label for='include'>Including</label>";
    $add .= "<input name='include'  type='text' value='".$includ."'>";
    $add .= '</br>';
    $add .= "<label for='duration'>duration</label>";
    $add .= "<input name='duration'  type='text' value='".$duration."'>";
    $add .= '</br>';
    $add .= "<label for='img'>img</label>";
    $add .= "<input name='image'  type='file'>";
    $add .= '</br>';
    $add .="<input type='submit' name='update'/>";
    $add .= '</fieldset>';
    $add .= '</form>';
    echo $add;

    if(isset($_POST['update']))
    {   
        $update_name = $_POST['user'];
        $update_price = $_POST['price'];
        $update_description = $_POST['description'];
        $update_address = $_POST['address'];
        $update_includ = $_POST['include'];
        $update_duration = $_POST['duration'];

        if ($update = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE trips SET title = ?, price = ? , description = ?, address = ?, includ = ?, duration = ?  WHERE id=?"))
        {
            $update->bind_param("ssssssi", $update_name, $update_price, $update_description, $update_address, $update_includ, $update_duration, $id);
            $update->execute();
        }
        else
        {
            echo "couldnt update";
        }
        header("Location: index.php?res=resources&adm=admin&page=inventory.php");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is apparently too localized question.

Comment: Because its unnecassary?

Answer (score 0):

one issue i see is that you issue an "echo" before calling "header(...)" in your update check routine so the page will not redirect as intended

Quote "Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP." [see PHP header manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)